# Microsoft.Solutions/applicationDefinitions internal server error

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to create a Service catalog managed application definition and get the following error :`{
  "error": {
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "Encountered an internal server error. The tracking id is '5d5bf382-f101-48d7-bd89-72c72536a4a9'."
  }
}`

Is there anyway to find out what causes this? I did come across before. And believe it might be something to do with the template. I've tested the following using visual studio and the deployments works correctly. Just uploading the app.zip with the templates causes this error.

Answer (score 0):

You can either look at the Azure Portal and go to Event Monitor and find error records and discern from the text there what went wrong or use `Get-AzureRmLog -CorrelationId GUID_goes_here` and look from there.

Comment: Thanks, I just get WARNING: Deprecation: The field EventChannels from the EventData object is being deprecated since it now returns a constant value (Admin,Operation)